# Is energy not conserved in a microscope?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction, microscopy

The Point Spread Function (PSF) of an imaging system is its impulse response and defines how a single point on the sample plane is *spreaded* on the image plane. The simplest model is the one calculated using Fourier optics without considering any aberrations and is defined by the following relation:

$$
h(r, z)=\left|\int_{0}^{1} \exp \left(-\frac{i k}{2} \frac{\mathrm{NA}^{2}}{n} \rho^{2} z\right) J_{0}(k \mathrm{NA} \rho r) \rho \mathrm{d} \rho\right|^{2}
$$

where $r$ is the radial coordinate in the image plane, $z$ the position along the optical axis, $k$ is the wavenumber of light, $n$ the refractive index, and $NA$ the numerical aperture of the lens used to acquire the image.

The PSF has the units of intensity, i.e. $J s^{-1}m^{-2}$. Thus, the energy collected by an (ideally infinitely large) detector at a fixed position in a fixed amount of time is

$$
E(z) = \int_T \int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty} h(r,z) rdr d\phi dt = 2\pi T \int_{0}^{+\infty} h(r,z) rdr
$$

The intuition says that $E$ should be constant along the $z$ axis because it's always the same amount of light, just spread differently of the $r$ plane because of propagation (i.e. diffraction). However, the numerical solution of the above integral is
[image]

where the focal position ($z=0$) is in the middle of the x-axis of the plot. I suspected that it could be just a matter of numerical precision, but this result keeps coming up independently from how I increase the precision of the calculation and the trend is always the same. Is this just a computational rounding error or is there a physical reason that explains the trend shown in the plot?

Of course, in the numerical calculation, I always chose an integration surface large enough to contain all the intensity.

Comment: Can I ask why you think the $z$-dependence is a numerical artifact? According to your formulas, $E(z)$ should vary with $z$.

Comment: @Codename47 because of the physical meaning of $E$. It's energy, if it varies with $z$ it means that some energy is lost somehow somewhere, but there is no reason to explain such a loss of energy along with the propagation of light.

Comment: I suspect the formula quoted for $h(r,z)$ is itself an approximation.

Comment: Betteridge's Law of Headlines most assuredly applies here

Comment: Even your question's text reads "the simplest model ...."  which should suggest to you that a full analytic solution will be different.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I admit that I used a clickbait title, but the question is real. The trend is different from the expected one and I am not sure of the reason. The "simplest model" does not mean "not analytic", I do not know why you should think differently. There are some assumptions behind (i.e. scalar diffraction theory, paraxial propagation, no aberrations, perfect lens, etc.) but none of them should point towards breaking the conservation of energy. That said, the derivation comes directly from Maxwell's equations.

Comment: @AndrewSteane The formula is derived using Fresnel diffraction, which you can see as a Taylor expansion of the complete Huygens-Fresnel integral. Is this enough to justify the shown trend? I have my doubts.